# Grouping PHP Array with Count

Tags: php, arrays

I have this sample of data, what I want to do is to group them together and count their occurence such that it form a new array

Is there a php function to count this occurence, noted that there are repeated "values", I want just a new array that show DISTINCT itemName with its counter (how many of it on the previous array below)

```
array("itemName" => $itemName,
"occurence" => $occurenceCount)


Array
(
    [0] => Baked halibut with diced tomatoes##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L
    [1] => Broiled nutty herb crusted salmon##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L
    [2] => Grilled n salted paprika chicken##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L
    [3] => Grilled n salted paprika chicken##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L
    [4] => Grilled n salted paprika chicken##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L
    [5] => Homemade Spanish beef balls##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L
    [6] => Homemade Spanish beef balls##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L
    [7] => Japanese chicken yakitori##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L
    [8] => Slow-cooked dory in bay leaves and thyme##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L
    [9] => Slow-cooked dory in bay leaves and thyme##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L
    [10] => Broiled nutty herb crusted salmon##bundle:10##gender:F##category:L
    [11] => Broiled nutty herb crusted salmon##bundle:10##gender:F##category:L
    [12] => Chilli con carne with minced beef##bundle:10##gender:F##category:L
    [13] => Chilli con carne with minced beef##bundle:10##gender:F##category:L
    [14] => Chilli con carne with minced beef##bundle:10##gender:F##category:L
    [15] => Homemade Spanish beef balls##bundle:10##gender:F##category:L
    [16] => Homemade Spanish beef balls##bundle:10##gender:F##category:L
    [17] => Yoghurt baked tilapia with bell peppers##bundle:10##gender:F##category:L
    [18] => Baked halibut with diced tomatoes##bundle:10##gender:F##category:L
    [19] => Japanese chicken yakitori##bundle:10##gender:F##category:L
    [20] => Broiled nutty herb crusted salmon##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L
    [21] => Broiled nutty herb crusted salmon##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L
    [22] => Chilli con carne with minced beef##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L
    [23] => Chilli con carne with minced beef##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L
    [24] => Homemade Spanish beef balls##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L
    [25] => Homemade Spanish beef balls##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L
    [26] => Japanese chicken yakitori##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L
    [27] => Yoghurt baked tilapia with bell peppers##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L
    [28] => Yoghurt baked tilapia with bell peppers##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L
)
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver Post it as answer. It's à solution ti the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php):

```
$result = array_count_values($array);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [Baked halibut with diced tomatoes##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L] => 1
    [Broiled nutty herb crusted salmon##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L] => 3
    [Grilled n salted paprika chicken##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L] => 3
    [Homemade Spanish beef balls##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L] => 4
    [Japanese chicken yakitori##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L] => 2
    [Slow-cooked dory in bay leaves and thyme##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L] => 2
    [Broiled nutty herb crusted salmon##bundle:10##gender:F##category:L] => 2
    [Chilli con carne with minced beef##bundle:10##gender:F##category:L] => 3
    [Homemade Spanish beef balls##bundle:10##gender:F##category:L] => 2
    [Yoghurt baked tilapia with bell peppers##bundle:10##gender:F##category:L] => 1
    [Baked halibut with diced tomatoes##bundle:10##gender:F##category:L] => 1
    [Japanese chicken yakitori##bundle:10##gender:F##category:L] => 1
    [Chilli con carne with minced beef##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L] => 2
    [Yoghurt baked tilapia with bell peppers##bundle:10##gender:M##category:L] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// $data contains your array

$counts = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    list($title, $bundle, $gender, $category) = explode('##', $value);
    if (isset($counts[$title])):
        ++$counts[$title];
        continue;
    endif;
    $counts[$title] = 1;
}

print_r($counts);
```

Dump of `$counts`:

```
Array
(
    [Baked halibut with diced tomatoes] => 2
    [Broiled nutty herb crusted salmon] => 5
    [Grilled n salted paprika chicken] => 3
    [Homemade Spanish beef balls] => 6
    [Japanese chicken yakitori] => 3
    [Slow-cooked dory in bay leaves and thyme] => 2
    [Chilli con carne with minced beef] => 5
    [Yoghurt baked tilapia with bell peppers] => 3
)
```